# Proving implicit function theorem using Kroneker-Rouchè-Capelli

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I'm a physics student facing the implicit function theorem. My professor gave me an unintuitive proof of the implicit function theorem based on Banach fixed-point theorem. I need help formalizing a more intuitive proof that I'm trying to give based on Kronecker-Rouché-Capelli's theorem.

Let the system of equations be written in vector form
$$
\mathbf f(\mathbf x, \mathbf y) = \mathbf 0
$$
Let $(\mathbf x_0, \mathbf y_0)$ be a solution of the system, meaning $\mathbf f(\mathbf x_0, \mathbf y_0) = 0$. Let ${\mathbf f}: \mathbb{R}^{n+m} \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be $\mathcal{C}^1$ in an open neighborhood of $(\mathbf x_0, \mathbf y_0)$. Thus we have that $\mathbf f$ is differentiable and by Taylor expansion we have

$$
{\mathbf f}({\mathbf x}, {\mathbf y}) = \underbrace{{\mathbf f}({\mathbf x_0}, {\mathbf y_0})}_{0} + D{\mathbf f}({\mathbf x_0}, {\mathbf y_0})({\mathbf x - \mathbf x_0}, {\mathbf y - \mathbf y_0}) + o(||({\mathbf x - \mathbf x_0}, {\mathbf y - \mathbf y_0})||);
\quad \text{for } {(\mathbf x, \mathbf y) \to (\mathbf x_0, \mathbf y_0)}
$$

By imposing $\mathbf(x, y)$ to be a solution of the system we get:

$$
\begin{aligned}
0 = &D{\mathbf f}({\mathbf x_0}, {\mathbf y_0})({\mathbf x - \mathbf x_0}, {\mathbf y - \mathbf y_0}) + o(||({\mathbf x - \mathbf x_0}, {\mathbf y - \mathbf y_0})||) \\
&D{\mathbf f}({\mathbf x_0}, {\mathbf y_0})({\mathbf x - \mathbf x_0}, {\mathbf y - \mathbf y_0}) = o(||({\mathbf x - \mathbf x_0}, {\mathbf y - \mathbf y_0})||) \\
&D{\mathbf f}({\mathbf x_0}, {\mathbf y_0})({\mathbf x}, {\mathbf y}) = D{\mathbf f}({\mathbf x_0}, {\mathbf y_0})({\mathbf x_0}, {\mathbf y_0}) + o(||({\mathbf x - \mathbf x_0}, {\mathbf y - \mathbf y_0})||) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Now since the columns of $D\mathbf f$ corresponding to $\mathbf y$ are independent by hypothesis (they give maximum rank $m$) we can use Kronecker-Rouché-Capelli theorem to state that for every fixed value of $\mathbf x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ there exists one and only one $\mathbf y \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ that satisfies the identity. This implies the existence of an implicit function: $\mathbf y = \mathbf g(\mathbf x)$ on all solutions of the system in the previously mentioned neighborhood of $(\mathbf x_0, \mathbf y_0)$.

*Now the problem*: this is not a proof, this is just the outline of a proof. Does the Kronecker-Rouché-Capelli theorem really say this? Where have I been to loose? How do I deal with the fact that $(||(−_0,−_0)||)$ is a function of $\bf y$?

I'd like to be helped in making this proof more rigorous or to be told that it is all wrong. If you could point me to an already existing proof based on Kronecker-Rouché-Capelli's theorem it would be more than enough.

Comment: never heard of Kronecker-Rouché-Capelli theorem, but upon googling, it's a simple linear algebra statement. Ok, so that on its own can never prove the implicit function theorem. Linear algebra, as the name suggests, deals only with linear maps. The implicit function theorem deals also with non-linear things. Also, you've completely disregarded the error terms. Banach's fixed-point theorem is one way of bridging the gap from the intuitive linear setting to the non-linear setting (and it is a powerful tool for generating existence theorems).

Comment: KRC theorem can be demonstrated applying the implicit function theorem to a linear system so the two theorems are connected. Linearizing a generic system around a particular solution and disregarding the error term, I gained intuition on their relation. Now that the intuition is there I have to deal with the error term to demonstrate that everything works. I don't know if this is possible. You say it isn't but you didn't give me any convincing reason for believing that. KRC is a linear theorem but since we talk about an infinitesimal surrounding it may be enough.

Comment: Krc is indeed a special case of IFT, but using IFT here is overkill. But the converse is what you're asking for. Information about derivatives is "infinitesimal behavior" but the IFT gives you local behavior (i.e on an entire open neighborhood). So the IFT is an infinitesimal to local theorem, and this can never be achieved by simple linear algebra only. The linear algebra certainly motivates the IFT (and I've written several answers regarding this intuitive motivation), but once you get down to the task of proving the general statement, it is obvious that linear algebra alone is insufficient.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it. The Jacobian matrix gives infinitesimal behavior information but this theorem isn't infinitesimal it's local which is much more. I will close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I think this question may be relevant for someone else I will answer myself referring to peek-a-boo's comment.

> Krc is indeed a special case of IFT, but using IFT here is overkill. But the converse is what you're asking for. Information about derivatives is "infinitesimal behavior" but the IFT gives you local behavior (i.e on an entire open neighborhood). So the IFT is an infinitesimal to local theorem, and this can never be achieved by simple linear algebra only. The linear algebra certainly motivates the IFT (and I've written several answers regarding this intuitive motivation), but once you get down to the task of proving the general statement, it is obvious that linear algebra alone is insufficient.